# Testing android implementation of cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, unit-testing, junit, cordova-plugins

I have created a cordova plugin which has an android implementation. This Java code has calls into an SDK that interfaces with specific hardware that the mobile device is connected to. I would like to write unit tests for my Java code and mock all the calls into the SDK so that I can run the tests during CI.

When looking into this, I found the [cordova-plugin-test-framework](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-test-framework), but from what I can tell, this is for tests that you would write against the javascript code, not the actual platform implementations. I'm sure I could use it and write some tests, but it would require the mobile device to be connected to the hardware, and I don't want to have actual calls into the SDK. In other words, I don't have a way of mocking the SDK calls using this.

I thought maybe I could just run JUnit from the command line with my Java code, but then I was getting errors because it couldn't find `org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext`. I tried faking my own object, but as I continued, I found more dependencies that my code in isolation just doesn't know about.

Next I figured it would be best to test it within the android project under `/platforms` in my ionic mobile app, since all the dependencies would be visible at that point. I'm able to run `./gradlew test` (https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html) from here, but I can't figure out how to implement the test cases so that this call will pick them up. Is there some kind of config I can add so it knows where to look for tests? I'd be fine if there was just a certain place I had to put them.

I'm open to any options with this. I just want to be able to run JUnit test as part of our CI process.

Comment: I have the same problem! Any solutions for this at this time?

Comment: @MS1 No, we never did find a solution for this.

Comment: I'm currently investigating how this could be done. Will inform you later of my findings.

Comment: I just answered a similar question with an idea how this might work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53543205/252627

Comment: As per October 2019. Is there a answer for this?

Comment: As per July 2022. Is there an answer for this?